# Publisher subscribe in Scala

Tags: scala, publish-subscribe

I'm new to scala, and I'm looking into the Publisher-Subscribe usage. There might be a problem with my Google skills, but I can't seem to find an example of this usage where I can specify which events should be observed by the subscriber.

Anyone got some examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you need something really simple, then I suggest do it your self, it should not be that hard. But if you want something bigger then you can look at [Eventbus](http://eventbus.org/api/index.html). It is Java lib, but I am using it with Scala too.

An example implementation in Scala is described in http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/10/simple-publishsubscribe-example-in.html

Comment: Well I've seen the tutorial of Jim McBeath, but actually I'm looking for an implementation of the Scale Publisher trait (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.1/scala/collection/mutable/Publisher.html)

Comment: I did not find one, too. What is stopping you exactly from the implementation? A Publisher will only publish one sort of event. But if this subject interest you, you can look into [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) from Ingo Maier, Tiark Rompf, Martin Odersky.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to monitor a class: as soon as any of its methods is finished, I want some monitor class to capture the event and do some stuff. So I'm looking for a way that each method of the publisher class automatically publishes when it is finished.

Comment: Then Eventbus should be for you, I think. Every method in a class can publish a specific event on the Eventbus, and you can define handlers that are interested in an event.

Answer (score 4):

An simple reference example can be found on http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/63002 :

```
case class MyEvent(number: Int)

class PrintIt extends Subscriber[MyEvent, Publisher[MyEvent]] {
  override def notify(pub: Publisher[MyEvent], event: MyEvent): Unit = {
    println("got an event: " + event)
  }
}

class RunIt extends Publisher[MyEvent] {
  def pub() = publish(MyEvent(12))
}

object Main extends App {
  val runIt = new RunIt()
  runIt.subscribe(new PrintIt)
  runIt.pub()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find a simple EventBus implementation here. It also does async event handling and scheduled event publishing.

https://github.com/hipjim/scala-event-bus

```
case class Msg(content: String)
val eb = EventBus()
eb.subscribe[Msg] { t =>
  println(t.content)
}

for (i <- 1 to 100)
 eb.post(Msg(i.toString))
```